How to force EF to allow, however ignore POCO Entity inheritence?
I have a peculiar situation that I have not run into before. The context is a code-generation framework I am building that stores a database-agnostic schema and generates all kinds of code against it in multiple languages.
The schema is mapped to .NET types and generates POCO entity classes, among other things. So I use entities such as follows:
Model // Represents the schema / database.
Entity // Represents the entity / database table.
EntityMember // Represents a property / database column.
Enumeration // Represents a list of values.
EnumerationMember // Represents a value in the list above.

Then, each model, entity, member, etc. can have multiple attributes (System.Attribute) attached to it. So I created a class to represent .NET attributes.
Attribute // Represents an attribute instance.
AttributeProperty // Represents the properties associated with each attribute along with their value expected at compile time.

So, the above structure could easily represent an attribute such as [Description("xyz")].
Now, I would need to create bridge tables (many-to-many) between attributes and other classes. The problem is, since attribute declerations are expected at compile time, I do not see a benefit gained from this approach.
Instead, I considered implementing an Attribite/AttrbuteProperty class pair separately as a one-to-many child of, Model, Entity, EntityMember, etc. I don't care about best practices at this point but also do not want to duplicate code that becomes error-prone and hard to maintain.
So my question is based on the following structure:
public class Model { }
public class Entity { }
public class EntityMember { }
public class Enumeration { }
public class EnumerationMember { }

public abstract class ModelAttribute
{
    public long Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string NameAssemblyQualified { get; }
    public Type AttributeTypeClr { get; }
}

public abstract class ModelAttributeProperty
{
    public long Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string NameAssemblyQualified { get; }
    public Type AttributeTypeClr { get; }
}

public class ModelEntityAttribute : ModelAttribute
{
    public long Id { get; }
    // ...Properties spcific to this combination...
    public long EntityId { get; }
    public Entity Entity { get; }
}

public class ModelEntityAttributeProperty : ModelAttribute
{
    public long Id { get; }
    // ...Properties spcific to this combination...
    public long ModelEntityAttributeId { get; }
    public Entity ModelEntityAttribute { get; }
}

public class ModelEnumerationAttribute : ModelAttribute
{
    public long Id { get; }
    // ...Properties spcific to this combination...
    public long EnumerationId { get; }
    public Enumeration Enumeration { get; }
}

//... and so on

If I do this, EF will map this as TPT, TPH, etc. I want to avoid that. How could I use the abstract classes while having EF ignore them and flatten the inheritance so to speak? In other words, I want EF to behave as if there were no base classes. Interfaces alone defeat the purpose of inheritance here.
Any guidance would be appreciated.

I don't think that's true. EF requires some explicit coding pattern, like DbSet<ModelAttribute> / modelBuilder.Entity<ModelAttribute>(...) to assume you want a type heirachy. Also you probably want to [NotMapped] your Type properties.

Though I would try to avoid building an "inner platform". Perhaps you should consider reusing EF's scaffolding with custom templates? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/templates?tabs=dotnet-core-cli. Though you'd need to work out how to construct your own table metadata without an existing database (see https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/213d37b17bf83933cd3d3f5a0fc60eeaf2b5fcbe/src/EFCore.Design/Scaffolding/Internal/ReverseEngineerScaffolder.cs#L18).

@JeremyLakeman: I wrote the code in this SO editor so skipped the [NotMapped] attribute for brevity. As for your second comment, It is a good suggestion, and one that I have looked into. The whole point of this project is to create a platform-agnostic platform that can read from, and feed to databases, ORMs, multiple languages etcetera. So it is much more than an 'inner platform'. It will eventually evolve into a product.
